# Как лучше хранить картинки приложения в drawable или assets

Tags: java, android, bitmap, android-drawable, android-assets

Приложение имеет сложный дизайн и по этому было решено делать прорисовку на surfaceView, то есть почти нет никаких xml файлов, все отрисовывается программно.  Но есть достаточно большое кол-во небольших png файлов, разного размера. Подскажите каким образом лучше хранить все эти файлы? варианты которые я рассматриваю: drawable - хранить в общей папке и изменять их размер программно, assets - все то же самое и есть третий вариант - загружать все картинки как атлас текстур в одном файле а потом создавать bitmap'ы по областям большого файла.
Опишите пожалуйста плюсы и минусы каждого варианта, может есть ещё какие-то варианты с которыми вы сталкивались?(Загрузка через интернет не подходит).

Comment: Почему не хотите стандартный способ, нарезанные картинки в папках `drawable-...dpi`? Не придётся каждый раз нагружать систему ресайзом. Переживаете за размер apk?

Comment: а это зависит что для вас важно, размер приложения, скорость работы, удобство и тд. Все варианты будут отличаться.

Comment: @eugeneek, Да, в таком случае размер сильно увеличивается, так как приложение использует все файлы практически постоянно, bitmap'ы хранятся в Singleton'e, и ресайзаются только при запуске приложения

Comment: @ShwarzAndrei, важно найти ту грань, где все эти параметры будут подобраны оптимально, Предполагаю, такой мой ответ повлечет предложение проверить все эмпирически для конкретного случая)

Comment: Битмапы в синглтоне звучит совсем плохо. Приближаете OutOfMemory таким способом. Я всё таки за вариант с нарезанными картинками и декодировании там, где нужно, а не хранении всего в памяти. Либо вектор, если картинки позволяют.

Comment: @eugeneek а каким образом может возникнуть OutOfMemory, если память выделилась под них один раз за все время работы приложения и больше никогда не увеличивается? Я не уверен, что вектор будет корректно работать на API 16, в предыдущем проекте приложение просто вылетало,возможно нужно подключить какую-то библиотеку... плохо осведомлен в данном вопросе(касательно поддержки вектора на предыдущих API)

Comment: @eugeneek в любом случае, все картинки используются практически одновременно, и под них будет выделяться память, а это ещё и время, по крайней мере когда смотрел на выделение памяти при отладке - все было в порядке

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Каталог `asset` принципиально отличается от `drawable` тем, что `drawable` позволяет хранить разные картинки для разных разрешений, ориентаций и локалей. `asset` же позволяет организовать хранение в виде как бы файлов.

Для вашего случая, я полагаю, `drawable` таки более предпочителен, поскольку вы можете организовать доступ через идентификаторы картинок, в случае же `asset` вам придется организовать доступ через как бы файловую систему, с чтением, организацией потока и проч., типа так:

```
public void loadImageFromAsset() {
    try {
        InputStream ims = getAssets().open("cat.jpg");
        Drawable d = Drawable.createFromStream(ims, null);
        mImage.setImageDrawable(d);
    }
    catch(IOException ex) {
        return;
    }
}
```

Теперь, вопрос касательно "пилить/не пилить" на картинки для разных `dpi`, принципиально это отличается только тем что в случае если вы не будете "пилить" картинки, то вы или накалываетесь на `OutOfMemoryException` на больших картинках, либо программно меняете разрешение картинки через `InSampleSize` (масштабирование картинки):

```
public static int calculateInSampleSize(
            BitmapFactory.Options options, int reqWidth, int reqHeight) {
    // Raw height and width of image
    final int height = options.outHeight;
    final int width = options.outWidth;
    int inSampleSize = 1;

    if (height > reqHeight || width > reqWidth) {

        final int halfHeight = height / 2;
        final int halfWidth = width / 2;

        // Calculate the largest inSampleSize value that is a power of 2 and keeps both
        // height and width larger than the requested height and width.
        while ((halfHeight / inSampleSize) >= reqHeight
                && (halfWidth / inSampleSize) >= reqWidth) {
            inSampleSize *= 2;
        }
    }

    return inSampleSize;
}
```

То есть выводите так:

```
// сначала проверяете реальный размер битмапа
final BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
BitmapFactory.decodeResource(res, resId, options);

//далее вычисляем inSampleSize
options.inSampleSize = calculateInSampleSize(options, reqWidth, reqHeight);

// теперь декодируем с правильным масштабированием    
options.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
Bitmap bimtap=BitmapFactory.decodeResource(res, resId, options);
//отображаем
imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
```

Подробнее [здесь](https://developer.android.com/topic/performance/graphics/load-bitmap.html)

Так вот в случае, когда картинки хранятся в раздельных `drawable-??dpi` - все эти вычисления делаются уже заранее. Тем самым экономится время на масштабирование картинок.

Вам решать, хотите вы заранее масштабировать или вы согласны часть процессорного времени убить на вычисления с масштабированием - зависит от задачи. Если решите не "пилить" картинки на разные `dpi` - складывайте их в `drawable-nodpi`.

По-поводу кэширования или асинхронной загрузки картинок. Существует довольно много различных либ, которые решают эту проблему, например [universal-image-loader](https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader) или новомодный [Picasso](https://github.com/square/picasso)

Comment: Спасибо, я думал обо всем вышесказанном, кроме идентификаторов и их отсутствия, для меня это критично, а на счет кэширования, скорее всего возьму picasso, так как это достаточно маленькая библиотечка (по весу), да и привык я к ней